# Python async socket - request trimmed (received partially)

Tags: python, sockets

I have written a Python async socket server, basically listens on port and responds to it. However, sometimes I observe that the request is sent partially e.g. the Content-Length indicates that the length is X but actual request received is kinda trimmed halfway. What could go wrong here?

```
SERVER_HOST = '127.0.0.1'
SERVER_PORT = 12345
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)                
server_socket.setblocking(False)
server_socket.bind((SERVER_HOST, SERVER_PORT))
server_socket.listen(5)          
inputs = [server_socket]
outputs = []
messages = {}

while True:
        for i in inputs:
                if i.fileno() < 0:
                        inputs.remove(i)
        for i in outputs:
                if i.fileno() < 0:
                        outputs.remove(i)
        readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs, 1)
        if not (readable or writable or exceptional):
                continue

        for s in readable:
                if s is server_socket:
                        connection, client_address = s.accept()
                        connection.setblocking(0)
                        inputs.append(connection)

                        messages[connection] = queue.Queue()
                else:
                        data = s.recv(self.params["buffer_size"])
                        if data:
                                messages[s].put(data)

                                if s not in outputs:
                                        outputs.append(s)

                        else:
                                # Interpret empty result as closed connection
                                if s in outputs:
                                        outputs.remove(s)
                                inputs.remove(s)
                                s.close()

                                del messages[s]
        # Handle outputs
        for s in writable:
                try:
                        next_msg = messages[s].get_nowait()

                        # handle next_msg here
                        handle(next_msg)
                except Exception as ex:
                        print('Error: ', s.getpeername(), ': ', ex)
                        outputs.remove(s)
                else:
                        s.sendall(response.encode("utf-8"))
                        outputs.remove(s)
                        s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
                        s.close()

# close socket
server_socket.close()
```

And based on the comments, the TCP is stream based, I changed a little bit on recv e.g. read all until no more.

```
for s in readable:
        if s is server_socket:
                # A "readable" server socket is ready to accept a connection
                connection, client_address = s.accept()
                print('new connection from', client_address)
                connection.setblocking(0)
                inputs.append(connection)

                # Give the connection a queue for data we want to send
                messages[connection] = queue.Queue()
        else:
                _data = s.recv(self.params["buffer_size"])
                if _data:
                        data = _data
                        while _data:
                                print('received "%s" from %s' % (_data, s.getpeername()))

                                try:
                                        _data = s.recv(self.params["buffer_size"])
                                        if _data:
                                                data += _data
                                except:
                                        break

                        # Add output channel for response
                        if s not in outputs:
                                outputs.append(s)
                        messages[s].put(data)

                else:
                        # Interpret empty result as closed connection
                        print('closing', client_address, 'after reading no data')
                        # Stop listening for input on the connection
                        if s in outputs:
                                outputs.remove(s)
                        inputs.remove(s)
                        s.close()

                        # Remove message queue
                        del messages[s]
```

But, still, there is a chance this will not work.

Comment: I don’t feel like trying to read and understand your entire program. If your question is that receiving tcp messages sometimes does not give you the entire message sent or combines multiple messages, that has been asked and answered SO MANY TIMES AT THIS POINT. That is the entire point of tcp. Otherwise, could you trim the code that you don’t need?

Comment: yes, trimmed down already..

Comment: So what exactly is your issue? The client is sending more bytes than the server is receiving?

Comment: **TCP is not message-based**. It is a byte stream. Keep reading until you read the whole message.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b yes.

Comment: @MarkTolonen  I tried that by reading until recv return nothing, and I have `Exception raised: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))`

Comment: @justyy That is strange, you should update your question with the new information.

Comment: @justyy It seems you are still only receiving once, and then looping over characters in it perhaps. You seem to have the right idea, but just be a little wrong on the implementation.

Comment: You mentioned a `Content-Length` header.  You don't read until `recv` returns nothing (indicating a closed connection).  You read *exactly* `Content-Length` bytes after the header.

Comment: @MarkTolonen Thank you. Yes, it solves my problem.. May I know why the recv returns 0 even there are data to be sent? This is different that what I thought it would be e.g. return 0 when there are no more data to send.